# Read numbers from os.Stdin into array or slice in Go

Tags: arrays, pointers, go, slice

I can read multiple numbers using multiple variables like bellow.

```
numbers := make([]int, 2)
fmt.Fscan(os.Stdin, &numbers[0], &numbers[1])
```

Can I use numbers itself not as separated shape to make it simpler?

```
numbers := make([]int, 2)
fmt.Fscan(os.Stdin, &numbers) // just an example, got error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package does not handle scanning slices, but you can create a utility function which packs the addresses of all the elements:

```
func packAddrs(n []int) []interface{} {
    p := make([]interface{}, len(n))
    for i := range n {
        p[i] = &n[i]
    }
    return p
}
```

And using this, you can scan a whole slice like this:

```
numbers := make([]int, 2)
n, err := fmt.Fscan(os.Stdin, packAddrs(numbers)...)
fmt.Println(numbers, n, err)
```

Testing it with [`fmt.Sscan()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sscan):

```
numbers := make([]int, 5)
n, err := fmt.Sscan("1 3 5 7 9", packAddrs(numbers)...)
fmt.Println(numbers, n, err)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iwSo5PxH-fh)):

```
[1 3 5 7 9] 5 <nil>
```