# The easiest (and possibly efficient) way to fill a slice from stdin/keyboard/command line/file in golang

Tags: go, input, operating-system, stdin

I have to write a simple program in go which takes some words separated from (,.: /n )and stores these words in a slice, from keyboard or command line or a .txt/xlsx/docx file (one program for each kind of input). Here on SO I have found these solutions:

[How to fill a slice with scan values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884144/how-to-fill-a-slice-with-scan-values)
[Reading a file line by line in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757389/reading-a-file-line-by-line-in-go)
[How to read/write from/to a file using Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821811/how-to-read-write-from-to-a-file-using-go)

But I'd like to know if there are some easier/most efficient ways to do this, especially without having to return all these nil values.
And I have the same problem with files. What is the most efficient/clean way to do this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just write it the best way you can and see if it's enough, then show us your code if it does not work. What I can recommend is using the `strings.Split` function for this. All you have to do is load input into one string and split it on the separator.

Comment: It's fine, but then what should I do? I thought to use bufio or Fmt.Scan, but I don't know how can I proceed.